# while installing ubuntu 15.10 alongside windows 8

Tags: dual-boot

I want to install Ubuntu alongside my windows 8 in D:/.My windows is installed in C:/.I have shrinked the D:/ for the installation.I have turned off the fast booting options,but I didn't got the UEFI settings. I started booting the system with  with bootable DVD,but it is showing error failed to load ldlinux.c32 .
Boot Failed :press a key to retry.

Answer (score 0):

The set up of 15.10 was not proper.The booting DVD doesn't contains any '.exe' files.so it was showing message of boot failed.I have now installed the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which is running perfectly with windows.